# How do I solve the: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause is not in the java path while working in Jboss/SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jboss

I'm new in stack overflow, I'm new to web programming.
So, I'm making a web app using JSP/servlets and I'm using java 6/jboss server.
When I try to connect to the server (I'm using the windows authentication, this means integratedSecurity=true in the string path) throws me the exception.
I already tried to put the DLL in the bin folder in the JBoss path, in system 32, and nothing seems to work. I'm using NetBeans, by the way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Paste the error stack trace here to review?

Comment: This is the regular exception:

09:36:05,552 WARNING [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.AuthenticationJNI] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
09:36:18,216 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Este controlador no está configurado para la autenticación integrada.

09:36:18,222 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

You've not added the path where sqljdbc_auth.dll is present. Find out in the system where the DLL is and add that to your classpath.

And if that also doesn't work, add the folder where the DLL is present (I'm assuming \Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\auth\x86) to your PATH variable.

1) Download the JDBC Driver [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

2) unzip the file and go to sqljdbc_version\fra\auth\x86 or \x64 
3) copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll to C:\Program Files\Java\jre_Version\bin 
4) Finally restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem try to change the name of dll files like is required in IDE [image]